# How to convert AppleScript URL type to string?

Tags: applescript

In AppleScript, I can cast some variables (e.g., the clipboard), to the built-in URL type:

```
set theURL to the clipboard as URL
```

If my clipboard contains an RTF link to https://temochka.com/, `theUrl` will be assigned a raw value like this (which can be seen in the Script Editor replies window):

```
«data url 68747470733A2F2F74656D6F63686B612E636F6D»
```

This last part (`68747470733A2F2F74656D6F63686B612E636F6D`) is a hex-encoded string that can be decoded as "https://temochka.com". Is there a way to extract just this value? Or maybe get the full URL value out?

Comment: Normally `the clipboard` contains several types (see `clipboard info`), so you should be able to just coerce to text.

Comment: Testing on my system where `set theURL to the clipboard as URL` returns `«data url 68747470733A2F2F74656D6F63686B612E636F6D»` it also returns `https://temochka.com` when using `set theURL to the clipboard as text`.  So is there some reason you can not just use `set theURL to the clipboard as text`?

Comment: @user3439894 try with a rich link that doesn’t match the URL. E.g., open Notes.app and create a link "website" that points to Google. `the clipboard as text` is "website" and `the clipboard as URL` is the URL.

Comment: temochka, Whether I copy the hyperlink from a **RTF** _document_ in **TextEdit** or from **Notes**, it does as I've stated in my first comment to the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `set theURL to the clipboard as URL` returns:

```
«data url 68747470733A2F2F74656D6F63686B612E636F6D»
```

Then if you are set on working with that *class*, you need to first write it to a temporary *file* and then read it back, as in the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
set tmpFilename to "/tmp/theURL.txt"

set theURL to the clipboard as URL

writeToFile(theURL, tmpFilename, true)

set theURL to read tmpFilename


on writeToFile(theData, theFile, overwriteExistingContent)
    try
        set theFile to theFile as string
        if theFile contains "/" then
            set theOpenedFile to open for access theFile with write permission
        else
            set theOpenedFile to open for access file theFile with write permission
        end if
        if overwriteExistingContent is true then set eof of theOpenedFile to 0
        write theData to theOpenedFile starting at eof
        close access theOpenedFile
        return true
    on error
        try
            close access file theFile
        end try
        return false
    end try
end writeToFile
```

---

**Notes:**

The `writeToFile(theText, theFile, overwriteExistingContent)` *handler* is a slightly modified *handler* from [Reading and Writing Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ReadandWriteFiles.html)

The *handler* from the linked **Apple** support document was modified to handle both **POSIX** and **HFS+** *file paths*.

When the clipboard returns what's show herein, it also can return `https://temochka.com` directly by using, e.g.:

```
set theURL to the clipboard as text
```

---

[image]

Comment: You’re a magician! I adjusted this a bit for my use case but writing to a temporary file and then reading it back actually does the trick. Thank you!

Comment: For posterity, this is the code that I ended up writing: https://github.com/temochka/macos-automation/commit/258bc5c44bf14dd0be843d018bb92e6b7d62ef53

Answer (score -1):

That's not what I get at all:

{class:URL, scheme:secure http URL, path:"https://temochka.com/", host:{class:Internet address, DNS form:"temochka.com", port:443, dotted decimal form:"159.203.68.102"}}

Comment: I’ve seen this behavior as well, but it only happens when the link text is itself a URL. If the link text is, say, "my homepage", then `the clipboard as URL` returns the described data object, not the URL class.

Comment: RE: "That's not what I get at all:" -- That's because you did not copy the link from a **RTF** _document_ where it is a hyperlink.

Comment: I just tried that, and I still got:

{class:URL, scheme:secure http URL, path:"https://temochka.com/", host:{class:Internet address, DNS form:"temochka.com", port:443, dotted decimal form:"159.203.68.102"}}